# date field criteria in access to have equal years

Tags: ms-access

I rarely use access but I need to update a query. How do I make it so a SERVICE DATE year and ADMIT DATE year equal each other?

Date fields currently show date like this: 20201015

Find year of Service: DOSYEAR: Left([svcdat],4)

Find year of Admit: DOAYEAR: Left([admdat],4)

I tried to create an additional column where the service and admit year equal each other like below and put "test" in the Field name. When I try to run though a parameter pop up appears. What do I need to change?

Left([svcdat],4) = Left([admdat],4)

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your expression to the top row, and replace it (in the criteria row) with **True**.

Comment: That is it. Thank you!